# Installed Eclipse GWT plugin, but no Web Application project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I have Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (3.7) installed on Windows XP and I installed Google plugin and GWT SDK , but even though plugin shows up as installed, I still do not get an option File > New > Web Application Project as it should be. And no icon with 'g' in blue circle on toolbar. What am I missing?

Thanks

Here is what I see on 'Plug-ins' tab in my Eclipse Installation Details screen:

Google App Engine Java SDK              1.7.6
Google Eclipse 3.7 Platform Plugin      3.2.2.v201303261859-r3l-r37
Google Eclipse Platform Plugin          3.2.2.v201303261859-r3l-r37
Google Eclipse Shared Platform Plugin   3.2.2.v201303261859-r3l-r37
Google Web Toolkit SDK                  2.5.1

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#multiuser (don't know if Eclipse 3.7 is concerned)

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Eclipse Market Place** --> Search For **GWT Plugin** --> Download **Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7**

It will take some time to download and install all the packages and plugins. But once it will be done, you will be able to see the google icon at the toolbar.

Also go through the following link.
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse

Comment: this is exactly how I installed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problen when following the GWT Tutorial  and  I fix the issue.

You can go:

Eclipse --> Help -->Install New Software --> Work with

Then paste, any of these urls but change indigo or helios for your eclipse IDE distribution

Indigo Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios

Wait a moment and Eclipse will show you all options.

Check the option:

Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development

Then click the Next, Apply and Finish and restart your IDE to see the changes.

Is all.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing [Java 7 JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Download and install the JDK from the above link, then [follow these instructions](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-with-java7.htm) to let Eclipse know where to find it.

After I installed Java 7, the GWT plugin buttons and menus finally appeared next time I started Eclipse.

Comment: Everything in here helped but this answer was the one that provided the solution in my case.

Comment: I followed these exact instructions and "Web Application Project" still does not appear under File > New.